# Left join on Hive - how to count NULLs as 0?

Tags: sql, join, hive, left-join

Let's say that I have a table Sales:

```
Sale_ID     Sale_date   Sale_amount
93480294    2017-01-01      100.00
12124343    2017-01-02      400.00
19859248    2017-01-01      130.00
65683748    2017-01-01      200.00
```

And a table Returns

```
Sale_ID     Return_date  Sale_amount
93480294    2017-01-03      100.00
```

I'm trying to create a total sales table that calculates the sale amount minus the returned sale_amount if it exists

so something like

```
select sales.sale_id, sales.sale_amount - returns.sale_amount
from sales_table sales left outer join returns_table returns on sales.sale_id = returns.sale_id
```

would return

```
12124343        NULL
19859248        NULL
65683748        NULL
93480294        0
```

but I need it to return

```
93480294        0
12124343        400
19859248        130
65683748        200
```

tl;dr - how can I count rows in the right column that don't appear in the left column as zeroes so that the difference can be calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
select sales.sale_id,
       coalesce(sales.sale_amount, 0) - coalesce(returns.sale_amount, 0)
from sales_table sales left outer join
     returns_table returns
     on sales.sale_id = returns.sale_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select sales.sale_id, sales.sale_amount - isnull(returns.sale_amount, 0)
from sales_table sales 
left outer join returns_table returns on sales.sale_id = returns.sale_id
```